# How can critical angle of attack of the wing of an an aircraft exceed even when the pitch angle is zero?

Tags: stall

Normally one would expect that if the pitch angle is zero, that is the aircraft is level on the artificial horizon, how would the wing present itself to the relative wind at such high angle that it exceeds the critical AOA.?

Comment: What about descending vertically with the fuselage horizontal? Pitch angle = 0°, AoA = 90°. Descending vertically will obviously be in a stall condition.

Comment: But doesn't the vertical dive still provide lift in the horizontal direction (when wings push the aircraft along horizontally, parallel to the ground)?I thought pointing the nose down straight does not make aircraft go straight down.

Comment: In this case, the lift of the wings will make the aircraft going a bit rearwards  while going down, due to the small angle of the wings named `c` on [this image](http://aerodynamique.chez.com/angle2.jpg) (*incidence angle*), but the wings will be stalled anyway. You need to have a [small pitch down angle](http://aerodynamique.chez.com/angle4.jpg) to really have no thrust and fall vertically (well the aircraft will not stay in this position for a long time).

Comment: The suggested duplicate is worded in the opposite way, but the explanation is the same: pitch and angle of attack are two different, only loosely related quantities.

Comment: @user2927392: He's not describing a dive (nose pointed down) but rather falling-out-of-the-sky: the aircraft is falling but the nose is pointed towards the horizon. Imagine a child dropping a toy plane instead of throwing it. While that scenario sounds stupidly ridiculous something like it can happen in a flat spin.

Comment: That's one of the factors in the crash of [QZ8501](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia_AirAsia_Flight_8501?wprov=sfla1). They were confused about the stall warning while the plane was wings level. They weren't accounting for the effect of sink rate on the AOA.